# ios - Loading an MP3 from remote URL and playing, freezing UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, avaudioplayer, dispatch-async

I am building a very simple app that plays a very small (less than 30 seconds of audio) static MP3 file from the Internet. The files are listed in a TableView and clicking on a cell opens a View that in turn loads and plays the remote MP3. Audio is played using the `AVAudioPlayer`. Please note that I am **NOT** attempting to stream live, continuous audio - just a brief clip. Here is an example of what I am trying to play - https://s3.amazonaws.com/tevfd-recording/All_Fire_and_EMS_2015-02-0314_38_54_457551.mp3

Initially, I downloaded the data of the MP3 file using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]`, which worked fine except for the fact that there is a delay between tapping a row and loading the view / playing the audio. One thing that I like about this approach is that the audio stops playing when the user leaves the View (back button press).

```
NSURL *callAudioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.call objectForKey:@"url"]];
NSData *callAudioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:callAudioURL];
AVAudioPlayer *audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData: callAudioData error:nil];
self.player = audio;
// Set slider to change position in audio
self.slider.minimumValue = 0;
self.slider.maximumValue = self.player.duration;
[self.player prepareToPlay];
[[self player] play];
self.updateTimer =     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateSeekBar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

In an attempt to eliminate the delay between the views, I wrapped the loading of the file in a call to `dispatch_async' -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        NSURL *callAudioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.call objectForKey:@"url"]];
        NSData *callAudioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:callAudioURL];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            AVAudioPlayer *audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData: callAudioData error:nil];
            self.player = audio;

            self.slider.minimumValue = 0;
            self.slider.maximumValue = self.player.duration;
            [self.player prepareToPlay];
            [[self player] play];
            self.updateTimer =     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateSeekBar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        });
    });
```

This works pretty well - the segue completes quickly and the data is loaded off of the main thread. However, if the user presses the Back button while the audio is playing, it continues.

My questions:
Am I on the right track with dispatch_async for this? If so, how should I go about killing the player when the user presses the Back button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably move away from using `-[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` and start managing the network operation yourself using `NSURLSession`. `-[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` is always going to load 100% of the data before playing anything, and it's synchronous, so calling it on the main thread is a good way to get the OS to kill your app for stalling the main thread. Doing the loading with `dispatch_async` keeps you from stalling the main thread, but doesn't solve the problem where it's going to load 100% of the data before you can do anything with it.

Comment: I'm brand new to iOS dev, less than a week. It would be much appreciated if you could show some code or perhaps point me in the direction of a tutorial. :)

Comment: LOL I just found it, perhaps should have tried Google before asking ;) Taking a short break, will try implementing in just a few. Thanks!

Comment: Please see updated question - wrapped everything in the completion block of NSURLSession and the app now crashes..

Comment: When the question changes so dramatically, you really ought to accept an answer to the previous question and move on to a new one. Regardless, you should probably go off and read more about NSURLSession in detail. The way you're using it here would *still* download 100% of the data before starting playback. Streaming audio data is a relatively complex task. There's not likely to be a 10 line solution that also delivers a good user experience.

Comment: To be clear, I am not trying to STREAM audio in the sense that it's live on the web, I essentially want to download it so that it may be played - with this in mind, wouldn't I WANT to download it 100%?

Comment: Well, that depends; Do you want your user to have to wait for the entire mp3 to download? Seems like a pretty crummy user experience to me.

Comment: I want the View that plays the audio to load quickly and then somehow prepare the audio for playing in the background. When it's ready, I want it to play. I accomplished this easily in Android, figure there must be a way in iOS. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: By the way, the MP3 file is tiny - less than a megabyte. About 30 seconds of audio.